# Как читать wss:// поток в php без библиотек (streaming api vk)

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, websocket

Streaming api vk позволяет получать события со всего вк, и реализовано это через wss:// протокол. 
Насколько я нагуглил, wss:// не поддерживается PHP по умолчанию.

[Документация по streaming api](https://vk.com/dev/streaming_api_docs_2?f=7.%20%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0):

Как это реализовать без использования библиотек/перекомпиляции php и т.д.?

UPD 1: по сути wss, это ssl над tcp, и в теории должен работать следующий код, но почему-то выдает 404 страницу.

```php
$socket = stream_socket_client("ssl://$endpoint:443/stream?key=$key", $errno, $errstr, 5, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT);

        $header = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" .
            "Content-Type:application/json\r\n" .
            "Host: localhost\r\n" .
            "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
            "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
            "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n\r\n";

        fwrite($socket, $header);

        while (!feof($socket)) {
            $context = fgets($socket, 1024);
            print_r($context);
        }

        fclose($socket);
```

Comment: В чём причина отказа от библиотек?

Comment: @ArchDemon, разрабатываю свою библиотеку, она небольшая, и не хотелось бы тянуть в зависимостях библиотеку в 10 раз больше собственной

Comment: Возьмите рабочую библиотеку и урежте её функционал. Так будет проще

Comment: @ArchDemon Так и сделал, код в UPD вопроса по сути и есть вырезанный и должен работать...

Answer (score 0):

Это получилось сделать! Правда подводных камней было много.
Для тех, кто попал сюда с таким же вопросом - прочитайте про [реализацию вебсокет протокола](https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket)

- Необходимо действительно стучаться на ssl:// с 443 портом.
- При отправке заголовков после подключения, необходимо query часть запроса засунуть вот в таком виде

> $header = "GET **/stream?key={$key}** HTTP/1.1\r\n" .
>               "host: streaming.vk.com:443\r\n" .
>               "user-agent:websocket-client-php\r\n" .
>               "connection:Upgrade\r\n" .
>               "upgrade:websocket\r\n" .
>               "sec-websocket-key: $key\r\n" .
>               "sec-websocket-version:13\r\n\r\n";
>           fwrite($this->socket, $header);

- Также должен присутствовать заголовок **sec-websocket-key** с сгенерированным ключом. Подробнее читайте на сайте про реализацию вебсокет протокола. Вот реализация генератора на PHP

```php
function generateKey() {
        $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"$&/()=[]{}0123456789';
        $key = '';
        $chars_length = strlen($chars);
        for ($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++) $key .= $chars[mt_rand(0, $chars_length - 1)];
        return base64_encode($key);
}
```

А дальше просто идет вычисление длинны payload, считывание payload, ловля PING сообщений от вк и отправка PONG.

Полностью класс реализации работы с Streaming вы можете посмотреть в моей [библиотеке](https://github.com/digitalstars/simplevk), либо в **master** ветке, либо в **testing** по пути **src/Streaming.php**. Там будет актуальная версия